# MLB The Show Players League

Tags: baseball, mlb

Some clip in a [MLB The Show Players League video](https://youtu.be/wJbiP8M_b9s?t=380) looks like some kind of video games. The guy pointed out by the red arrow seems to be manipulating a playstation controller.

[image]

Is "MLB The Show Players League" some kind of video game?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it is a question about video games, which are not sports](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/).

Comment: If you have any more questions about the video game you should ask them on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is "MLB The Show Players League" some kind of video game?

"MLB: The Show" is a video game.

"MLB The Show Players League" is a league of players, one from each MLB team, playing MLB: The Show, a video game.

[This article](https://www.mlb.com/news/30-stars-compete-in-mlb-the-show-players-league?t=video-games-coverage) sums up "MLB The Show Players League" quite succinctly:

> The “MLB The Show” players league will provide fans an opportunity to
>   watch their favorite players play the video game [MLB: The Show], while also allowing
>   them to interact with them through various streaming services.